# Merging rows in python csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a csv file that contains data like that

**Sample csv**

| Name | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| John | 12:10 | 13:00 |
| John | 12:20 | 13:20 |
| Tom | 12:00 | 13:10 |
| John | 13:50 | 14:00 |
| Jerry | 14:00 | 14:30 |
| Alice | 15:00 | 16:00 |
| Jerry | 11:00 | 15:00 |

I need to perform Merging operation on overlapping intervals
Before merge

- John [12:00,13:00],[12:10,13:00],[12:20,13:20],[13:50,14:00]
- Jerry [14:00,14:35],[11:00,15:00]
- Tom [15:00,16:00]
- Alice [12:00,13:10]

After merge

- John [12:00,13:20],[13:50,14:00]
- Jerry [11:00,15:00]
- Alice  [12:00 ,13:10]
- Tom [15:00,16:00]

I am trying to use python CVS for that

```
import csv

dict = {}
with open('log.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        Name = row["Name"]
        rows = [row["Start"], row["End"]]
        if Name not in dict.keys():
            dict[Name] = [row["Start"], row["End"]]
    print(dict)

for entry in dict:
    print(entry,row["Start"], row["End"])
```

I am not sure how to approach that problem.

Comment: Do you _want_ to have two different `John`s after the merge just because they're not consecutive in the original table? Or are you just assuming is going to be easier that way? And if you actually want two, then please shown how the table would look like: should they be together or the "second John" should be after Tom?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)? (like being tied to an environment where it's not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with pandas it could look like this:

```
import pamdas as pd

df = (pd.read_csv('file_01.csv',parse_dates=['Start','End']).
      sort_values(['Name','Start']))

df['split'] = (df.groupby('Name').
               apply(lambda x: (x.Start>x.End.shift().bfill()).cumsum()).
               droplevel(0))

res = (df.groupby(['Name','split']).
       apply(lambda x: [x.Start.min().strftime('%H-%M'),x.End.max().strftime('%H-%M')]).
       groupby('Name').
       apply(list).
       to_dict())

>>> res
'''
{'Alice': [['15-00', '16-00']],
 'Jerry': [['11-00', '15-00']],
 'John': [['12-00', '13-20'], ['13-50', '14-00']],
 'Tom': [['12-00', '13-10']]}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic here how you got the split row?  Using of bfill() cumsum()